# Steam on HiDPI screen

Tags: steam, hidpi

Has anyone gotten steam to show scaled on an HiDPI screen in elemntary os? It should be working in the steam beta client by enabling "Enlarge text and icons based on monitor size" but this does not work for me. I have also tried passing GDK_SCALE=2 but this also does nothing.

I should note I had the same issue on Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 beta. Is it not working any longer in steam or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "GDK_SCALE=2 steam" works for me, but the "Enlarge text and icons based on monitor size" is checked but does not stick.